# How to remove main activity from back stack?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, back-stack

I have a main `activity(M)(host activity)` and few full page size `fragments(f1,f2,f3)`.My main activity is a empty page and I am not showing anything into it. When app starts I am showing `fragment f1` by default. But when I am pressing back button I am landing on white page of my main activity(M).I don't want activity M in my backstack .How can I remove that ?
I tried `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` before activity started but Its not working also I tried `finish();` after start activity but it is also not working.Any Idea ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I think the way your fragment f1 appears is wrong. Another trick would be to override the onBackPressed() method but that's not recommended.

Comment: Must read Fragment and its lifecycle once http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the first fragment to the back stack. Then pressing back while on the first fragment will exit the application.